# Laravel 5.2 Using raw query when defining self-referencing model relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

When calling `CollegeMajor::with('majors')->get()`, I would like to apply the following raw sql query:
 `TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(parent_id, ':', -1) FROM parent_id)` to the `parent_id` column. The values in parent_id are stored as `1:1234, 1:3121, 1:1332` etc... and so therefore I'd like to strip everything after the colon. The primary key for CollegeMajor is id and those values are integers like `1`. I get the error below because Laravel believes the raw query is the name of the column. How do I tell Laravel to apply that sql query to `project_id` column when executing the relationship?

CollegeMajor.php

```
class CollegeMajor extends Model {
   public function majors() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CollegeMajor', \DB::raw(TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(parent_id, ':', -1) FROM parent_id)))
                  ->where('entity', 'major');
   }
}
```

Error

```
Unknown column 'college_major.TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(parent_id, ':', -1) FROM parent_id)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `college_major` where `entity` = major and `college_major`.`TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(parent_id, ':', -1) FROM parent_id)` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
```

college_majors table

```
id      name             entity   parent_id
1   College of Art       college     1234
2   College of Business  college     4567
3   Art History          major     1:1234
4   Asian Art            major     1:1234
5   Accounting           major     2:4567
6   Marketing            major     2:4567
```

How to make it return?

```
[
  id: 1,
  name: 'College of Art',
  entity: 'college',
  parent_id: 1234,
  majors: [
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Art History',
      entity: 'major',
      parent_id: '1:1234'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Asian Art',
      entity: 'major',
      parent_id: '1:1234'
    }

  ]
  ....
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter for `hasMany()` is the foreign key. So you cannot define your query there. Define your relationship as follows.

```
public function majors() { 
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CollegeMajor'); 
}
```

Then when you query use [raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions) this.

```
CollegeMajor::with('majors')
     ->select(DB::raw('TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(parent_id, ":", -1) FROM parent_id))')
->where('entity', 'major')->get();
```

Not yet tested. On my phone :)

Comment: Very close i think. I've edited my question. The collection is what I'm trying to achieve. Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated the answer as I forgot to add `get()` at the end of the query. Then it would return a collection.

Comment: I had to do some hacky solution where I get all the results from the table, filter the results by colleges only, add a 'majors' key to each of those college objects, then loop through each record and if its a major, then I loop through each of the college objects and push that major to the college it belongs to. By far an elegant solution but i think it'll do for now.